# Public static objects holding single data even if different users using

Tags: asp.net, object, c#-4.0, iis-7

I create web application in Visual studio 2015 and I publish it.

when my users try to access the site and adding data to the page , user 1 seeing another user data on his browser while click on save or refresh that page.

in pages I am using Public static objects of my class and holding data in these object until I click on my final save.

Answer (score 0):

Static variable scope is application wide and such variables persist for the lifetime of the app domain. So all your users will share it. Store user specific data in Session object, for example.